# OCR finding paragraphs or sections

Tags: android, ocr, scanning, android-vision

I'm currently using Mobile Vision SDK for OCR (https://developers.google.com/vision/), but I'm getting lot of sequence in finding blocks.

Can anybody help me to arrange blocks for sequencing blocks correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The position of blocks is reported as a part return value. 
Can you use that to arrange blocks?